# Wie soll ich Negation auf Deutsch gebrauchen?

Tags: verb, negation, auxiliary-verb

Welche ist die richtige Option?

1. Ich mache Wasser nicht trinken.
2. Ich trinke Wasser nicht.
3. Ich trinke kein Wasser.

Und warum?

Comment: Unlike English, German does not use an auxillary verb for negation.

Comment: Danke für Ihre Hilfe.

Comment: The correct answer is 3. *Ich trinke kein Wasser.* Answer 2 ist acceptable but not too common. Answer 1 is wrong. If you replace *mache* with *tue*, it's correct in some dialects.

Comment: Your title and your question are two different things. Can you edit one of them, so they match each other?

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: (1) is totally bad (afaik "I make drink no water" is very bad also on English). But as the comments show, and as your improvements show that your post imho deserves a reopen vote. You need 4.

Comment: Als Hilfsverb in (1) kommt "tu" in Frage, "Ich tu Wasser nicht trinken", das ist aber sehr umgangssprachlich und nicht mal verbreitet. Wenn jmd. einen 5L-Kanister Wasser die Treppe raufträgt könnte jmd. anmerken: "Da hat aber einer Durst!" worauf Du antworten könntest: "Ich *trinke* Wasser nicht. Ich brau damit Bier." Ansonsten ist die "kein"-Variante dominierend.

Comment: Dank an alle für Ihre Hilfe.